# Filtering/Querying Pandas DataFrame after multiple grouping/agg

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, having

I have a dataframe that I first group, Counting QuoteLine Items grouped by stock(1-true, 0-false) and mfg type (K-Kit, M-manufactured, P-Purchased). Ultimately, I am interested in quotes that ***ALL*** items are either NonStock/Kit and/or Stock/['M','P'] :

```
grouped = df.groupby(['QuoteNum', 'typecode', 'stock']).agg({"QuoteLine": "count"})
```

and I get this:

```
                                 QuoteLine-count
QuoteNum    typecode    stock   
10001          K          0         1
10003          M          0         1
10005          M          0         3
                          1         1
10006          M          1         1
...           ...        ...       ...
26961          P          1         1
26962          P          1         1
26963          P          1         2
26964          K          0         1   
               M          1         2
```

If I unstack it twice:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['QuoteNum', 'typecode', 'stock']).agg({"QuoteLine": "count"}).unstack().unstack()

# I get
    QuoteLine-count
stock           0                       1
typecode    K       M       P       K       M       P
QuoteNum                        
10001       1.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
10003       NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
10005       NaN     3.0     NaN     NaN     1.0     NaN
10006       NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0     NaN
10007       2.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
...         ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
26959       NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0
26961       NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0
26962       NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0
26963       NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     2.0
26964      1.0      NaN     NaN     NaN     2.0     NaN
```

Now I need to filter out all records where, this is where I need help

```
    # pseudo-code
    (stock == 0 and typecode in ['M','P']) -> values are NOT NaN (don't want those)
    and 
    (stock == 1 and typecode='K') -> values are NOT NaN (don't want those either)

so I'm left with these records:
Basically: Columns "0/M, 0/P, 1/K" must be all NaNs and other columns have at least one non NaN value
```

```
    QuoteLine-count
stock           0                       1
typecode    K       M       P       K       M       P
QuoteNum                        
10001       1.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
10006       NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0     NaN
10007       2.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
...         ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
26959       NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0
26962       NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     1.0
26963       NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     2.0
26964      1.0      NaN     NaN     NaN     2.0     NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, use boolean mask to set rows that match your conditions to `NaN` then unstack desired levels:

```
# Shortcut (for readability)
lvl_vals = grouped.index.get_level_values

m1 = (lvl_vals('typecode') == 'K') & (lvl_vals('stock') == 0)
m2 = (lvl_vals('typecode').isin(['M', 'P'])) & (lvl_vals('stock') == 1)
grouped[m1|m2] = np.nan
out = grouped.unstack(level=['stock', 'typecode']) \
             .loc[lambda x: x.isna().all(axis=1)]
```

Output result:

```
>>> out
         QuoteLine-count            
stock                  0       1    
typecode               K   M   M   P
QuoteNum                            
10001                NaN NaN NaN NaN
10006                NaN NaN NaN NaN
26961                NaN NaN NaN NaN
26962                NaN NaN NaN NaN
26963                NaN NaN NaN NaN
26964                NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: Glad to read that! If this solution suits to your need, don't forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: Just wanted to add that your solution marked records that I am looking for with NaN and only thing I've added is to filter on following

out[out.isna().all(axis=1)]

Comment: I updated my answer according to your comment. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

Desired values could be obtained by `as_index==False`, but i am not sure if they are in desired format.

```
grouped = df.groupby(['QuoteNum', 'typecode', 'stock'], as_index=False).agg({"QuoteLine": "count"})

grouped[((grouped["stock"]==0) & (grouped["typecode"].isin(["M" ,"P"]))) | ((grouped["stock"]==1) & (grouped["typecode"].isin(["K"])))]
```

Comment: Thanks @hakanerdem. I tried your solution: it ended up including quote 10005 because it contains an 1/M count, but this quote should be excluded because it contains a 0/M count

Comment: @Shreko thanks for your comment. Maybe,  i misunderstood the problem:)